# Capacities on Load-balancer & Web Servers? Bandwidth + Performance

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, bandwidth, load-balancing

I'm on **DigitalOcean** and I have a very simple scenario for my website.

- Now having `3000` concurrent hits every minutes. (For example)
- Currently it is directly on 1 only single Apache Server.
- **The website CAN NOT be Cached**. (for some sensitive reason)

Then I am thinking for simply advanced setup, like:

- 1x Software Load Balancer (e.g, Nginx)
- 3x Apache as Web Servers .. at behind LB.

Then suddenly my simple (but BIG) questions are:

- `Load Balancer` or `Web Servers`. Which ones should have better CAPACITIES, in terms of `BANDWIDTH` and `PERFOMANCE`.

Lets say LB redirects `1000` connections to each Web Servers. Does it mean:

1. The LB still need to consume 3000 Traffic Bandwidth IN+OUT?
2. Each WebServer still need to consume 1000 Traffic Bandwidth IN+OUT?
3. LB should have big PROCESSING performance? Or, the WebServers?

---

### To be more dummy ..

Something like ..

- Do I need to buy $80 / month for LB Droplet (and, leave $20 Droplets for WebServers)?
- (or) Do I need to buy $40 / month 3x WebServer Droplets (and, leave $10 Droplet for LB)?

Comment: Is the content being served session sensitive? Can a user's session move between the 2+ servers?

Comment: ........... Yes

Comment: 1. yes
2. yes (internal)
3. no. yes.